# Why does the condition in the function not work?

Tags: html, jquery

Why does the condition in the function not work?
Please tell me why the .not() condition does not work.

```js
$(".one").not(".two").on("click", function() {
  console.log("click one");
})
```

```css
.one {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
}
.two {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
  <input type="file" class="two">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because of event [bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing).

When you click on `.two`, as it is a child of `.one`, the click event happens also on `.one`

To prevent this, you can use [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation?retiredLocale=it) **but it might not be the right choice** as it - indeed - stops the event propagation to every other element, and this could not be desirable if there are other events you listen to in your code and introduce bugs. Stopping propagation of events is something that should be used carefully:

- [Dangers of stopping Event propagation](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/)
- [Pros/Cons of using e.stopPropagation()](https://localcoder.org/pros-and-cons-of-using-e-stoppropagation-to-prevent-event-bubbling)

**Another** - and in my opinion preferred - **option** is to use the [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) and [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). The first is the element to which the event is attached (`.one` in your case). The second is the actual HTML element that has been clicked.

So, you can check if the event.target is `two` or `one` and code different behavior for each alternative.

```js
$(".one").on("click", function(event) {
  console.log("event.target is: ", event.target);
  console.log("event.currentTarget is: ", event.currentTarget);

  if ($(event.target).hasClass('two')) {
    console.log("Mmh... you clicked two, please click one");
  } else if ($(event.target).hasClass('one')) {
    console.log("YEAH! You clicked one this time");
  }
})
```

```css
.one {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
}

.two {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0px;
}

.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 4.5em !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
  <input type="file" class="two">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can I bypass the click by selecting the file?

Comment: For the sake of completeness of this answer, you can also remove the `not('.two')` here as well

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".two").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: `stopPropagation()` is an option but [not always the best one](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/). Also [here](https://localcoder.org/pros-and-cons-of-using-e-stoppropagation-to-prevent-event-bubbling). I edited my answer to explain it.